# Python 3.1.3 Win 7: csv writerow Error "must be bytes or buffer, not str"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Got a simple script which worked perfectly under Python 2.7.1 at my Win xp machine.
Now got a win 7 machine with python 3.1.3.

The code is:

```
owriter.writerow(dtime[1][1])

dtime[1][1]=['30-Aug-10 16:00:00', '2.5', '15']
```

Got this error message: `TypeError: must be bytes or buffer, not str`

What changes should I make?

thanks.

Comment: When you upgraded from Python 2 to Python 3, did you run [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) on your script?

Comment: owriter=csv.writer(outputfile), no i didn't run 2to3.

Comment: and what is `outputfile`? post your actual code. This is not even remotely comprehensible.

Comment: just ran the 2to3, no change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you need to open the file in text mode. If not, include enough of your code so it's runnable and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Very nice remark; Windows' text/binary file modes are common gotcha.

Comment: Thanks. the code is: outputfile=open("out.csv",'wb') owriter=csv.writer(outputfile) owriter.writerow(dtime[1][1]) outputfile.close()

Comment: @steve So take away the `b` flag. CSV files are not binary, they should be opened in text mode.

Comment: @steve: and why are you opening file with `'wb'`?

Comment: @steve: And indeed you do open it in binary mode, as suspected. Changing it to text mode solves the problem.

Comment: Well, it *is* 100% correct. It's not just complete. :-) This is interesting as this is an example of a module in the stdlib that breaks the Python 3 rule of not changing it's API, while there is no fixer for it!

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: The definition of text mode vs binary mode changed from 2.X to 3.X. In 2.x all it meant was: in text mode on Windows aka Visual CP/M, convert external CRLF <-> `\n` and stop reading on '\x1a`. In 3.x its meaning was changed: on any platform, convert external bytes <-> str. Newline handling was split out into the `newline` option. Consequently the csv API had to change.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: [continued] The best one could hope for from 2to3 would be warning messages "you may need to change the way that 'csvfile' is opened" on detecting csv.reader|writer. It would be nice if csv.writer checked immediately whether the file looked OK instead of getting the unhelpful message that the OP got -- WHAT "must be bytes or buffer"?

Comment: @John Machin: Sure, bt if the API changes, there should be a fixer or a Python2.6 -3 warning. The problem is that the parameters are to the file opening, which means making a fixer is extremely difficult. That mmeans -3 should warn, which it doesn't, or opening in binary mode in Python 3 should warn or fail, which it doesn't. This is IMO a bug in Python.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: When you submit a bug report, please add `sjmachin` to the "nosy" list :-)

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: [OT] There are other situations where the real problem is one step away and it's hard to make a fixer e.g. `ord(raw_bytes[i])` which needs to become merely `raw_bytes[i]`. I regard changing the result of `raw_bytes[i]` from 1-byte `str` to `int` a major change in API; what do you think?

Comment: @John Machin: Done! http://bugs.python.org/issue10954 I dont' think the difference in api between Python 2 str and Python 3 bytes is an API change as such. :) Maybe it is, but it's also one of the fundamental changes, no point in warning for that. But libraries API shouldn't change without warning.

Answer (score 16):

In Python 2.X, it was [required](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.writer) to open the csvfile with 'b' because the csv module does its own line termination handling.

In Python 3.X, the csv module still does its own line termination handling, but still needs to know an encoding for Unicode strings.  The correct way to open a csv file for writing is:

```
outputfile=open("out.csv",'w',encoding='utf8',newline='')
```

`encoding` can be whatever you require, but `newline=''` suppresses text mode newline handling.  On Windows, failing to do this will write \r\r\n file line endings instead of the correct \r\n.  This is mentioned in the 3.X [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader) documentation only, but [csv.writer](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.writer) requires it as well.

Comment: +1 As it happens, I should be trying to answer the request for a doc-patch after I raised a bug report about the 3.X csv.writer docs -- http://bugs.python.org/issue7198 -- thanks for the reminder :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change to `str.encode("ascii")`.

The point is that Python 2.x had somewhat mixed usage of `str` type for storing *byte buffers* and for storing *character strings*. Now in Python 3.x we have proper Unicode support and byte buffers are now separate type. You can convert between them using `str.encode()` and `bytes.decode()` specifying each time a [character encoding](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) as parameter.

Comment: @steve it is a method of string objects. You must use them as `"foo bar".encode("utf-8")`.

Comment: @steve note that in your case you shouldn't open CSV files in binary mode and [Lennart's answer][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739066/python-3-1-3-win-7-csv-writerow-error-must-be-bytes-or-buffer-not-str/4739193#4739193 ] is the right solution.