# Issue in writing result into csv file using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I am using python 2.7 in my Windows 10(64-bit) system. I have a string *str*, when executed it shows result as :-

```
'abcd'
'wxyz'
```

Now, I want to write this result into result.csv file. So I wrote this following python scrip:-

```
import csv
with open('result.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
     csv_write = csv.writer(csv_file)
     csv_write.writerow([str])
```

But whenever I execute this script, I am finding only *wxyz* in result.csv file.

Help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should never name your objects after built-ins like `str`

Comment: Can you post the entire script, seems like a little bit of information is missing

Comment: Based on your comment to my answer, you should update your post to show the full picture here. I think some code is missing...

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 `csv` likes the `'b'` mode for writing (in Python 3 just `'w'`).

**Example:** Pre-built list of `string` to file

```
import csv

strings = []
s1 = 'abcd'
s2 = 'wxyz'
strings.append(s1)
strings.append(s2)

csvf = r"C:\path\to\my\file.csv"

with open(csvf, 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for s in strings:
        w.writerow(s)
```

**Example:** Use of `reader()` to build list of rows to supply `writer()`

```
import csv

# read current rows in csv and return reader object
def read(_f):
    with open(_f, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    return reader

# writes the reader object content
# then writes the new content to end
def write(_f, _reader, _adding):
    with open(_f, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in _reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
        for row in _adding:
            writer.writerow(row)


strings = []
s1 = 'abcd'
s2 = 'wxyz'
strings.append(s1)
strings.append(s2)

csvf = r"C:\path\to\my\file.csv"

content = read(csvf)

write(csvf, content, strings)
```

**Example:** Quick append

```
import csv

strings = []
s1 = 'abcd'
s2 = 'wxyz'
strings.append(s1)
strings.append(s2)

csvf = r"C:\path\to\my\file.csv"

with open(csvf, 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for s in strings:
        writer.writerow(s)
```

**References:**

In [Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader), the `reader()` and `writer()` objects required a `'b'` flag upon opening. This was a result of how the module handle line termination.

In [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) this was changed so that `reader()` and `writer()` objects should be opened with `newline=''`; line termination is still handled however.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739066/python-3-1-3-win-7-csv-writerow-error-must-be-bytes-or-buffer-not-str) post and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv) post covering some of this.

Comment: Thanks for the information @pstatix. But I want to extract 'abcd' and 'wxyz' from str and and write it to csv file.How should I do it?

Comment: @user3766871 What do you mean by "extract...from str"? If you have a variable called `str` and those values are inside it; that's a whole other question.